# How to convert matplotlib animation to an HTML5 <video> tag

Tags: python, html, matplotlib

Below there is the code of a matplolib animation graph and [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.Animation.html) is how to save it.

```
from IPython.display import HTML
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation 
import numpy as np

t = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi)
x = np.sin(t)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.axis([0,2*np.pi,-1,1])
l, = ax.plot([],[])

def animate(i):
    l.set_data(t[:i], x[:i]);

ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=len(t));
#HTML(ani.to_jshtml())

ani.to_html5_video()
```

What I basically do is copying the generated code into a basic html script like this one:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<video width="432" height="288" controls autoplay loop> BLABLA </video>
</body>
</html>
```

Graph is not showing but the heading and the video menu is there. Why? How can I fix it?

Comment: I think this question lacks the very important step of how `ani.to_html5_video()` is related to `BLABLA`. Possibly you just made a mistake copying one to the other?

Comment: Hey, the link I get is super long so I did not wanted to copy paste it all and I found no way to attach a file. Here is a link to it in my drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bGpBR5zoHFD_MCzZLuIaUWT3H0OVeHeO/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just stating `ani.to_html5_video()` will not give you the correct string out.
If you look closely at what you have copied, you will see linebreaks (`\n`) all over the output. (I marked them in the screenshot...)

[image]

Use

```
print(ani.to_html5_video())
```

to obtain the HTML code of the video. Or, to directly save to a file

```
with open("myvideo.html", "w") as f:
    print(ani.to_html5_video(), file=f)
```

---

**Explanation**

As an explanatory example, take

```
string = "Hello\nWorld"
```

If you state `string` in the cell it will produce

```
'Hello\nWorld'
```

But if you `print(string)`, it will give you the interpreted string

```
Hello
World
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `to_html5` function has a default `embed_limit` of 20 MB.

```
If the embed_limit is exceeded, this returns the string "Video too large to embed."
```

My guess would be that your animation exceeds this limit. As you define the `<video>` tag in the HTML, the heading and controls get generated nevertheless.

You could take a look on the generated document to see if the video body just says "Video too large to embed." If this is the case, you can try to increase the `embed_limit`.