# Matplotlib - Why is my saved animation video blank?

Tags: python, matplotlib, ffmpeg

This should be pretty simple but I just don't know.

A newbie to Python and FFmpeg. Just trying to save a test video from ArtistAnimation but got blank video.

Before I tried to produce the video, I can see the animation by plt.show() (without "matplotlib.use("Agg")" ). I have already installed FFmpeg in Anaconda as well.

To ensure my FFmpeg is functioning, I used the code from [matplotlib example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/animation/basic_example_writer_sgskip.html) and produced a video that looks perfect. (I guess this means my FFmpeg will work fine from now on?)

Then, I only changed the figure to my version. Having compared the figure part, I didn't see anything wrong obviously. But in the saved video of my version, it's blank.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as ani
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


fig = plt.figure()
ims = []
for i in range(10):
    ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 2), (0, 0), colspan=2, rowspan=2)
    data = np.random.normal(0, 1, i+1)
    pd.DataFrame(data).plot(kind='bar', ax=ax1)
    ims.append([ax1])



# Set up formatting for the movie files
Writer = ani.writers['ffmpeg']
writer = Writer(fps=15, metadata=dict(artist='Me'), bitrate=1800)

anim = ani.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=500, repeat_delay=3000, blit=True)
anim.save('textmovie.mp4', writer=writer)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Are you sure that ffmpeg is installed? An alternative would be to try using [to_html5_video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55163024/how-to-convert-matplotlib-animation-to-an-html5-video-tag).

Comment: What is the command being issued to ffmpeg? Show the complete log from the ffmpeg process.

Comment: I used the [matplotlib example] (https://matplotlib.org/gallery/animation/basic_example_writer_sgskip.html) which can produce a normal video in my PC. So I guess that means the FFmpeg is installed correctly?

Comment: Could you please tell me how to show the complete log from the ffmpeg process? I'm using PyCharm. Thanks!

Comment: @patrickxya I don't know anything about python or PyCharm, but ffmpeg will output the log to stderr, or add the `-report` option and it will output an extra verbose log file in the working directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution using [celluloid](https://pypi.org/project/celluloid/).

There could be a way to create the animation using `ims.append`, but I couldn't find one.

For the solution to work, you need to place `ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 2), (0, 0), colspan=2, rowspan=2)` before the loop.

Here is the code:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as ani
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from celluloid import Camera

fig = plt.figure()
camera = Camera(fig) #  https://pypi.org/project/celluloid/
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 2), (0, 0), colspan=2, rowspan=2)
for i in range(10):
    data = np.random.normal(0, 1, i+1)
    pd.DataFrame(data).plot(kind='bar', ax=ax1)
    camera.snap()

# Set up formatting for the movie files
Writer = ani.writers['ffmpeg']
writer = Writer(fps=15, metadata=dict(artist='Me'), bitrate=1800)

# anim = ani.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=500, repeat_delay=3000, blit=True)
anim = camera.animate(interval=500, repeat_delay=3000, blit=True)
anim.save('textmovie.mp4', writer=writer)
```

Result:
[image: camera animate]

Answer (score 0):

For me, removing the blit=True did the trick. I think it has something to do with the fact that if blit=True then you need to return all the artists that have gotten modified but I am not sure. In my case I was changing the viewing angle (ax.azim) which probably changed the rendering of everything I had plotted. I was returning ax, from the animate function. Hopefully someone more knowledgeable than me would comment on this.